# Spring-data-neo4j map cannot be cast to nodeentity

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using Spring-data-neo4j but meet the following problem.

Everything works fine until I want to cast the queried LinkedHashMap to an @NodeEntity. Here's the code

Movie.class

```
@NodeEntity
public class Movie {
@GraphId Long id;

@Property(name="title")
private String mtitle;

@Property(name="released")
private String mreleased;

@Property(name="tagline")
private String mtagline;

@Relationship(type = "REVIEWED", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private Set<Movie> reviewed;

@Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private Set<Movie> actedIn;

@Relationship(type = "DIRECTED", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private Set<Movie> directed;
}
```

They repository

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends GraphRepository<Movie>{
    @Query("MATCH (n) WHERE id(n)={0} RETURN n")
    Movie getMovieFromId(Integer idOfMovie);
}
```

When using `getMovieFromId()` in the service, I get the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.domain.Movie
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.getMovieFromId(Unknown Source)
com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.services.GLService.getGL(GLService.java:24)
com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.controllers.GLController.getGLOverview(GLController.java:22)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

The movie node in the neo4j contains property 'title', 'released', 'tagline', and relationship 'ACTED_IN', 'DIRECTED' and 'REVIEWED'.

BTW, if I change the repository type from `Movie` to `HashMap`, the exception gone.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what the repository definition looks like, as well as more of the stacktrace?

Comment: @Luanne I have add full version of the repository and exception.

Comment: Is there no part of the stacktrace from org.neo4j.ogm?

Comment: @Luanne I don't think so. Everything is here.

Comment: Hmm. Stupid question but can you check if your Movie package is included in the ones you supply to the SessionFactory?

Comment: @Luanne Yes, I am quite sure about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105965/discussion-between-luanne-and-steven-luo).

Comment: @Luanne OH MY DEAR GOD! I found a typo in the sessionfactory. Problem solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ha, cool. I'm going to add this as an answer in case someone else has the same problem. Appreciate an accept, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check if the Movie package is included in the ones supplied to SessionFactory. The OGM will map to the entity if it knows that it's a domain entity (i.e. scanned when the SessionFactory is instantiated), otherwise, it'll just send back the Map of data.